# Mozilla Firefox Quantum 63.0: "Restore previous session" greyed out

Tags: firefox, restore, firefox-extensions

Today, I read about some tricks to make my Firefox more secure [here](https://vpnpick.com/make-firefox-secure/) and [here](https://vikingvpn.com/cybersecurity-wiki/browser-security/guide-hardening-mozilla-firefox-for-privacy-and-security), and went on to implement some of them. After I was done doing this stuff, I got to see that "Restore previous session" is not highlighted.

When I restarted my FF I found only a blank page. Unfortunately, I implemented the suggestions in one go.... and not able to track back.

How to re enable "Restore previous session", now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meantime, I undid all the changes I might have done... ... but nothing worked. Later, I figured that Firefox was set for '**do not remember history**'. I changed it and everything was OK!!